# Binding Command in TemplatedColumn in RadDataGrid UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp, telerik

I am developing a UWP application and I need to show data in RadDataGrid control of Telerik. In one scenario I need to show data using TemplatedColumn and bind commands to controls placed inside its DataTemplate but command are not getting triggered in ViewModel but when I attach event to these controls events get triggered in code behind.

Here is the code:

```
 <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">
        <Core:CallMethodAction MethodName="LoadData"
                               TargetObject="{Binding}" />
    </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

 <Grid x:Name="gdRoot">

    <telerikGrid:RadDataGrid ItemsSource="{x:Bind AvailableVM.PickListItems,Mode=OneWay}"
                             Background="{StaticResource GridLinesBrush}"
                             SelectionUnit="Cell"
                             GridLinesBrush="{StaticResource GridLinesBrush}"
                             AlternateRowBackground="{StaticResource AlternateRowBackground}"
                             AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
            <telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Assign"
                                                SizeMode="Auto">
                <telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Background="Transparent"
                                    Command="{Binding DataContext.ListSelectedCommand, ElementName=gdRoot}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
            </telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
    </telerikGrid:RadDataGrid>
</Grid>
```

here is the ViewModel Code:

```
private ICommand _listSelectedCommand;

    public ICommand ListSelectedCommand
    {
        get { return _listSelectedCommand; }
        set { Set(nameof(ListSelectedCommand), ref _listSelectedCommand,value); }
    }

 public void LoadData()
    {
        InitializeCommands();
    }
private void InitializeCommands()
    {
        ListSelectedCommand= new RelayCommand(()=>
        {

        });
    }
```

What could be the possible reason behind this.

Answer (score 0):

The most possible reason for the command does't work should be you didn't bind the command correctly. Since your code snippet is not the full, the incorrect binding may be caused by many reasons. Here is a small demo I tested which can work on my side you may reference.

XAML:

```
<telerikGrid:RadDataGrid ItemsSource="{x:Bind AvailableVM.PickListItems,Mode=OneWay}"
                 Background="White"
                 SelectionUnit="Cell"
                 GridLinesBrush="Pink"
                 AlternateRowBackground="Azure"
                 AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                x:Name="radgrid">
    <telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
        <telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="Country"/>
        <telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="City"/>
        <telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Assign"  SizeMode="Auto">
            <telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:DataTest">
                    <Button Background="Transparent"  Command="{x:Bind ListSelectedCommand }" Content="command testing" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
        </telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns> 
</telerikGrid:RadDataGrid>
```

Code behind:

```
public ViewModel AvailableVM { get; set; }
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    AvailableVM = new ViewModel(); 
}

public class ViewModel
{ 
    public void Testmethod()
    {

    }          
    public ObservableCollection<DataTest> PickListItems { get; set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        PickListItems = new ObservableCollection<DataTest>()
        {
            new DataTest { Country = "Brazil", City = "Caxias do Sul",  ListSelectedCommand = new RelayCommand(()=>{ })},
            new DataTest { Country = "Ghana", City = "Wa",  ListSelectedCommand = new RelayCommand(Testmethod)},
            new DataTest { Country = "Brazil", City = "Fortaleza"} 
        };
    }
}

public class DataTest
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public ICommand ListSelectedCommand { get; set; }
}
class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    private Action _action;

    public RelayCommand(Action action)
    {
        this._action = action;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this._action();
    }
}
```

By the way, the `CellContentTemplate` may have influences on binding. Tried to bind on the above way. Also the `RadDataGrid` has its own [commands](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/universal-windows-platform/controls/raddatagrid/features/commands/datagrid-overview) you can refer if there is one suit your scenario.

Comment: Thanks @Sunteen. I have found the reason behind this. Here is the Link https://www.telerik.com/forums/what-is-the-correct-way-to-bind-a-command-on-button-in-template.